# Issues using Entity Framework to update a row

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to maintain a SQL Server database. I need to update a row if it exists, and create the row if it does not. Pretty simple.

The following is a code snippet:

```
var snapshot = new funnelSnapshot();
snapshot.Year = cvStudent.EffectiveDate.Year;
snapshot.Week = GetWeekNumber(cvStudent.EffectiveDate);
snapshot.Status = cvStudent.StatusDesc;

var week = context.funnelSnapshots
                  .Where(x => x.Year == snapshot.Year && 
                              x.Week == snapshot.Week && 
                              x.Status == snapshot.Status)
                  .FirstOrDefault();

if (week != null)
{
      week.Count += 1;;
      context.SaveChanges();
  }
  else
  {
       snapshot.Count = 1;
       context.funnelSnapshots.Add(snapshot);
       context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

The table looks like this:

[image]

When the code runs, the row is updated when found, however, a row is also inserted. I cannot figure out why the row is inserted.

Please help

Comment: what is snapshot and how was this snapshot object created?

Comment: Yes on the save changes. I also include the snapshot object

Comment: Where does that new fragment fit in with the 1st code block? This is a logic error so understanding the whole sequence of events is critical.

Comment: edited the snippet to place things in order

Comment: There is no way for this code to simultaneously update and add a row. There must be something else.

Comment: Now what is cvStudent? Are you using relationship in Models? If any of your other entities having reference of funnelSnapshot were instantiated earlier in the code and the reference was also instantiated in the constructor or with any ORM feature, then you may be adding this instance as well to context, while adding the other entity to it.

Comment: There seems to be some extra context that we are not seeing. But as a fix, have you tried only creating a new snapshot in the "else",  so when variable week == null? You would only need to update the query so that it doesn't use the snapshot.XXX values

Comment: I restructured my code as was suggested by Hitesh and Juan and it works. Not sure what I was doing wrong. I appreciate the input.